# Performance with an encrypted disk

Tags: hard-drive, performance, storage

Is Raspberry Pi (model B, rev. 2) suitable for a home file server with *external* disks encrypted with LUKS? In particular, is the de/encryption throughput reasonable? I used to have such a disk in a dual core Atom machine and the performance was OK (mostly bound by network throughput and the CIFS protocol). Using Pi would be somewhat nicer - less power consumption, no noise from the power supply etc.

With 100Mbit ethernet I'd be more than happy if the throughput were somewhere between 5-10MB/s. And > 1MB/s would still be reasonable for most operations.

Comment: Welcome to the Raspberry Pi corner of the Stack Exchange.  What sort of data throughput are you anticipating - the 10/100 MHz wired Ethernet shares bandwidth with the built-in 4 port USB Hub so the data transfer rate is not going to be *stella* but it may be *good-enough* if you can quantify your requirements.  One thing proviso is that the most recent Raspian (Jessie) distribution as well as most (I guess) of the others use the, ahem, *modern* `systemd` by default, rather than the system V `init` of the previous Wheezy.  IIRC that did have some issues with *exotic* features of encrypted fs s.

Comment: @SlySven I updated the Q. You're right, Jessie has problems with encrypted disks, actually one of the reasons I'm considering Pi is that the original machine got into unusable state after attempting to upgrade to Jessie so I'll have to reinstall the system one way or another.

Comment: Fortunately, Debian has retained the capability to use the older (30+ years?) sysV `init` with the Jessie (8.x) release and that **has** been ported to Raspbian which is derived from it. If you are trying to dist-upgrade from Wheezy (7.x) do what I have on all my systems, Pin `init` so that `systemd` NEVER gets a look in - see [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/217200/if-i-upgrade-from-debian-wheezy-7-x-to-jessie-8-x-will-systemd-run-by-defau) and [here](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/release-notes/ch-information.en.html#systemd-upgrade-default-init-system)...

Comment: ... those ARE for PC platform, but the notes in the previous section, especially [4.4.4](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html#minimal-upgrade) in that second link may help even on an RPi! *Note: I am not speaking from an impartial viewpoint, so please be aware that my suggestion to keep with `init` is laden with personal bias - you never know, maybe they have/will fix `systemd` to work better with LUKS.* 8-/

Comment: @SlySven Seems that in [#618862](https://bugs.debian.org/618862) near the end a workaround is suggested that might help.

Answer (score 3):

So I tried that out and it works pretty nicely so far (except for [some problems with the 4.1.18 kernel](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/43552/9326)). Using cipher *aes-xts-plain64* the **speed is around 3MB/s** for both reading and writing.

Answer (score 0):

Other SOCs in the same price range have much better encryption performance:

aes-xts 512b benchmarks:

```
MiB/s,   Product
   9.7,  RPI 1
  18.8,  HiFive Unmatched (U740)
  22.5,  RPI 3
  42.2,  Odroid C2
  60.0,  USB2 ===
  66.1,  RPI 4
  76.2,  Odroid XU4
 221.2,  UP1
 240.3,  Orange Pi PC2, NanoPi NEO2 (AllWinner H5)
 267.0,  espressobin
 370.5,  ROCK64 (RK3328)
 570.6,  Odroid C4 (S905X3)
 625.0,  USB3 ===
 655.6,  Odroid N1, ROCKPRO64, etc (RK3399)
 666.1,  UP2 (N4200)
 704.2,  Odroid H2 (J4105)
 707.1,  Odroid N2 (S922X)
 826.1,  rackspace (E5-2670)
 985.1,  EC2 (AMD EPYC 7571)
1366.7,  EC2 (E5-2676)
1393.7,  old i5 (2500S)
2710.3,  Ryzen 1800X
2994.5,  i7-1165G7
```

https://forum.odroid.com/viewtopic.php?f=149&t=30103