# Can't mount volume encrypted with aes-xts-plain64 after upgrading to Jessie

Tags: kernel, raspbian-jessie, mount, storage, software-compatibility

I have an encrypted disk attached via USB. After upgrading to Jessie, I'm not able to mount it any more, getting error

```
Check that kernel supports aes-xts-plain64 cipher (check syslog for more info)
```

I tried to load different modules in `/lib/modules/*/kernel/crypto`, but with no success.

Answer (score 1):

After some searching and getting together multiple pieces of information, I found a solution. tl;dr:

```
sudo rpi-update 0764e7d78d30658f9bfbf40f8023ab95f952bcad
```

and reboot.

---

In more detail: On [aes-xts-plain64 support on linux-lts-4.1.18-1](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=209034) I found that the problem appears in 4.1.18. It's apparently a regression, here is the [bug](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=112631). Reverting to 4.1.17 fixes the problem.

Post [Easiest way to upgrade/downgrade Raspberry Pi kernel](http://blog.wcypierre.com/easiest-way-to-upgradedowngrade-raspberry-pi-kernel/) describes how to do it. In particular, it's necessary to find the appropriate commit hash in https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-firmware/, which is [0764e7d7](https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-firmware/commit/0764e7d78d30658f9bfbf40f8023ab95f952bcad) for 4.1.17, and then use `rpi-update` to switch to it.